# string convresion from input file

Tags: python, utf8-decode

i'm new to python and i need some hand to work this code:

this code works right, it converts strings as i need.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u' الحركات')
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
print >>open('out', 'w'), reshaped_text.encode('utf-8') # This is ok
```

I get the following error when i try to read the string from a file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

with open ("/home/nemo/Downloads/mpcabd-python-arabic-reshaper-552f3f4/data.txt" , "r") as myfile:
data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')    
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(data)
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
print >>open('out', 'w'), reshaped_text.encode('utf-8')
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).

Any hand

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method decode() decodes the string using the codec registered for
>   encoding. It defaults to the default string encoding.

*When you reading **utf-8 encoded** file, you need to use [string.decode('utf8')](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_decode.htm)*

***Write:***

```
data = 'my data'
with open("file.txt" , "w") as f:
    f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
```

***Read:***

```
with open("file.txt" , "r") as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the optional `encoding` parameter of the built-in [open function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open):

```
with open("/home/nemo/Downloads/mpcabd-python-arabic-reshaper-552f3f4/data.txt",
          'rt',
          encoding='utf8') as f:
```